# Inner element (of type sting array) in scope object is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

Inner element (sting array) in scope object is not working with ng-repeat

```
    $scope.fakeoptions = ["Option1","Option2"];

    $scope.Question= {
        Title: "New Question Title",
        Options: ["Option1","Option2"],

    };
```

This is not working

```
   <div ng-repeat="option in Question.Options" class="col-sm-3">
   <input type="text" value="{{option}}" />
   </div>
```

where in case this working

```
<div ng-repeat="option in fakeoptions " class="col-sm-3">
<input type="text" value="{{option}}" />
</div>
```

i am new to angular, in knockout i was using something like observable
Please assist.

Comment: Both are working. Please check once again.

Comment: use `ng-model` instead of `value` in input types. It will work.

Comment: yes ng-model is working now where in first option is not workin still, Thanks Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going wrong as it works fine, see the snippet below. Do note however that you should use ng-model to bind the values to the inputs and you really shouldn't bind directly to the scope values, but that has little to do with the issue you're describing.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.fakeoptions = ["Option1", "Option2"];

  $scope.Question = {
    Title: "New Question Title",
    Options: ["Option1", "Option2"],

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">


    <div ng-repeat="option in Question.Options" class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" value="{{option}}" />
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="option in fakeoptions " class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" value="{{option}}" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes. ng-model is working now where value="{{option}}" is still not workin, Thanks Robba

Comment: Good to see you got it to work. One final note though, whenever you use ng-model, you should really try to make sure there's a "dot" in the thing you're binding to. See this document for some pretty good explanation on the quirks of the Scope structure in Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes